# Why is my gaussian np.array not symmetric?

Tags: python, numpy, gaussian

I am trying to write a function that returns an `np.array` of size `nx` x `ny` that contains a centered gaussian distribution with mean `mu` and sd `sig`. It works in principle like below but the problem is that the result is not completely symmetric. This is not a problem for larger `nx` x `ny` but for smaller ones it is obvious that something is not quite right in my implementation ...

For:

```
create2dGaussian (1, 1, 5, 5)
```

It outputs:

```
[[ 0.   0.2  0.3  0.1  0. ]
 [ 0.2  0.9  1.   0.5  0. ]
 [ 0.3  1.   1.   0.6  0. ]
 [ 0.1  0.5  0.6  0.2  0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0.   0.   0. ]]
```

... which is not symmetric. For larger `nx` and `ny` a 3d plot looks perfectly fine/smooth but why are the detailed numerics not correct and how can I fix it?

```
import numpy as np


def create2dGaussian (mu, sigma, nx, ny):
    x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-nx/2, +nx/2+1,nx), np.linspace(-ny/2, +ny/2+1,ny))
    d = np.sqrt(x*x+y*y)
    g = np.exp(-((d-mu)**2 / ( 2.0 * sigma**2 )))


    np.set_printoptions(precision=1, suppress=True)
    print(g.shape)
    print(g)
    return g
```

----- EDIT -----

While the below described solution works for the problem mentioned in the headline (non-symmetric distribution) this code has also some other issues that are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430086/2d-gaussian-function-does-not-produce-correct-results).

Comment: but this is a symmetric matrix.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? `nx/2` will yield different results depending on your Python version

Comment: python 3 (I have fixed this part according to the suggestions below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy's `linspace` is inclusive of both edges by default, unlike `range`, you don't need to add one to the right side. I'd also recommend only dividing by floats, just to be safe:

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-nx/2.0, +nx/2.0,nx), np.linspace(-ny/2.0, +ny/2.0,ny))
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it is symmetric but the middle is lower (0.6) - so possibly I have a different problem as well in my code?

Comment: @lordy Dunno. Open a new question for that if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @lordy My guess without actually looking into it is that that's the correct answer, since the sum of the area under the gaussian is expected to be 1, thus for sigma > 0, the peak of the gaussian must necessarily be < 1 (0.6 sounds pretty sane).